# How to reduce image size into 50 to 100kb while updating into database in android

Tags: android

How to reduce captured image size while uploading into db, It's take so much  time to uploading and so much time to downloading to. Please help me on this one, How to resize image to 100kb.. Help me fast.

```
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    final int maxSize = 1024;
    int outWidth;
    int outHeight;
    int inWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
    int inHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
    if (inWidth > inHeight) {
        outWidth = maxSize;
        outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
    } else {
        outHeight = maxSize;
        outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
    }

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, outWidth, outHeight, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget all the Thing.

Just do this

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap,(int)(yourBitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(yourBitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);
```

Comment: How much size that my image consists after using this code?

Comment: @HarishReddy Use your `Image` and resize it. and Check how it resize.

Comment: @HarishReddy if this not help then tell me I will give another way.

Comment: @HarishReddy change it to `Int` because it's my typing mistake.

Comment: showing error like "expected   actual", "parameters  arguments"

Comment: @HarishReddy glad to help you.